# PSN_QUERYCANCEL does not close Property Sheet

Tags: c++, c, winapi, propertysheet

I have a property sheet that I have created and each of the tab pages share the same `pfnDlgProc`. In the `pfnDlgProc`, I have this code:

```
switch (msg) {
    case WM_NOTIFY:
        nmhdr = (NMHDR*)lParam;

        switch (nmhdr->code) {
            case PSN_QUERYCANCEL:
                printf("PSN_QUERYCANCEL\n");
                SetWindowLong(nmhdr->hwndFrom, DWL_MSGRESULT, FALSE);

                return TRUE;
        }

        break;

    ...
}
```

When I click the Cancel button on my property sheet, `PSN_QUERYCANCEL` is printed, but the property sheet does not close. Why is this? Is there something else I need to do to allow it to/make it close? I know I can add `DestroyWindow(nmhdr->hwndFrom)` to the handler but is that the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the DWL_MSGRESULT on the window handle that sent you the notification, but not necessarily the window that is the dialog you are processing the WM_NOTIFY for. Instead of using the nmhdr->hwndFrom window handle, try using the HWND that is passed to your pfnDlgProc.